# What is the English name for these two geometric formulae?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I'm looking for an English name of ["定比分點公式"](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AE%9A%E6%AF%94%E5%88%86%E7%82%B9%E5%85%AC%E5%BC%8F).  There's a page on the Chinese Wikipedia dedicated for the vector version of this formula, but that's only available in Chinese.  I copy the relevant section of its content so that you don't have to click the linked Wiki page to see what it's about.

> $${\overrightarrow {AD}}={\frac {|{\overrightarrow {CD}}|}{|{\overrightarrow {BC}}|}}{\overrightarrow {AB}}+{\frac {|{\overrightarrow {BD}}|}{|{\overrightarrow {BC}}|}}{\overrightarrow {AC}}$$
> [image: wiki median jpg]

Here's the first case of the area version of this formula that is well-known in the Chinese literature.  It can be found in many Chinese journals and books, say Zhang Jing-zhong's (張景中) book *新概念幾何* (, which literally means "new concept geometry" and which has not been translated into other languages).  I take the following picture from [*Fan's Math World*](https://fanhongtao.github.io/math/ding-bi-fen-dian-gong-si.html).

> $P$ and $Q$ are on the same side of the plane divided by line $AB$, and line segment $PQ$ doesn't not intersect with line $AB$.  Point $C$ lies on line segment $PQ$ such that $PC = \lambda PQ$.  Then we have
> $$S_{\triangle ABC} = \lambda S_{\triangle QAB} + (1 - \lambda) S_{\triangle PAB}.$$
> [image: fan's math world fixed ratio]
> Remarks:
>
> 1. $S_{\triangle ABC}$ means "the area of $\triangle ABC$".
> 2. I didn't put the word "segment" in between "line $AB$".  To understand why, consider the second case of the area version of this formula: line segment $PQ$ intersect with line $AB$ at point $M$.  Then $\triangle MAB$ degenerates into line segment $AB$ or $AM$ or $BM$, so it has area zero.  However, on the right hand side, the area of both $\triangle PAB$ and $\triangle QAB$ and both coefficients $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$ are positive.  Hence, we have zero LHS and positive RHS, which is absurd.
>
> ```
>             P
>           / |
>    A----B---M
>           \ |
>             Q
> ```

Both versions make use of the a point on a line segment whose distance with the endpoints follows a fixed ratio.  I asked on Discord Math server, and a guy told me that he would call it something like "convex interpolation", but I didn't find relevant pages on DuckDuckGo the search engine.

Comment: I would call the first *vector interpolation*

Comment: With your absurd result, it becomes less absurd if you give the areas signs

Comment: If you only care about magnitudes, the first result is called [Stewart's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem)

Comment: ... which has a different [Chinese Wikipedia page](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%AF%E5%9B%BE%E5%B0%94%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%86)

Comment: the vector denoted $AD$   is a **convex combination** of $AB, AC.$  That is,  $\vec{AD} = p \vec{AB} + q \vec{AC} $ with $p+q=1  \; \; \;$   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is also found in the book *Machine Proofs in Geometry* by Zhang Jing-zhong (whom you mentioned) coauthored with Chou Shang-Ching and Gao Xiao-Shan, which *is* available in English (as well as online [on the website of one of the authors](http://www.mmrc.iss.ac.cn/%7Exgao/paper/book-area.pdf). However, it is not named in that book either.

The following preliminary result does have a name - it is named the **Co-side theorem**:

> Let $M$ be the intersection of lines $AB$ and $PQ$ and $Q \ne M$. Then we have $\frac{S_{PAB}}{S_{QAB}} = \frac{\overline{PM}}{\overline{QM}}$.

(As with your formula, this also requires the use of signed areas to be correct in all cases.)

The formula $$S_{ABC} = \lambda S_{ABP} + (1-\lambda) S_{ABQ}$$ can be proven easily from the co-side theorem, which is possibly the reason that the authors of *Machine Proofs in Geometry* only refer to it as "Proposition 1.18" (and later "Proposition 2.9").

When teaching this material I refer to the formula  as "linearity of signed area" because, literally, it says that $S_{ABC}$ is an affine-linear function in one of the points $A$, $B$, or $C$. (This also follows from the determinant formula for the area of a triangle.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link of the book, and your explanation.  The introduction of signed area is a great tool that I'll explore.